# Using a StringBuilder to return to a $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, cross-domain, stringbuilder

I'm trying to send back a WebService return to a Jquery Post using **StringBuilder** but the Jquery Post always get a error.

I'm using a proxy page to call a **Webservice** because the call is cross domain.

To call the proxy page I'm using this Jquery Post:

```
$.post("http://localhost/test/callWS.aspx/recordvideo", 
                 { eId : eId, 
                   id : iId,
                   usu_id : userId,
                   video : video })
.done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
})
.fail(function() { 
        alert("error");
 });
```

The **callWS.aspx** is the proxy page and the **recordvideo** is the WS method.

This is what I use to return in CallWS.aspx  page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string result = "";
            string[] call = Request.PathInfo.Split('/');
            result = jsonSerialize(invokeMethod(typeof(WebService.EForm), call[call.Length - 1].ToString()));
            sb.Append(result);    
            Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.End();

        }
```

So, how can I send back the WS return without errors using this methods ?

Comment: Surely it should be a `GET` if it's a request _getting_ data.

Comment: the StringBuilder in that code is doing nothing. Just return result.

Comment: I have to send a video so it should be sending as Post(because of the request size) and i have to return to the $.Post a status

Comment: I don't think you need anything you have in your `Page_Load` method.. you should just have a static method called `recordvideo` (though that doesn't follow naming standards) which returns a string (probably serialized). Asp.net should handle the rest.

Comment: No, even returning just the jsonSerialize result, i have the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Response.End(). The response end will give you a exception.